# How do you install a binary R package?

Tags: libraries, r

I need instructions on how to install a binary package in R.

Comment: If its an executable, it should be able to self-install.  Did you try executing it?

Comment: Shouldn't a question like this be better posed to a mailing list for R users?

Comment: Can you dish out more details?

Comment: A similar question was closed on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8719487/how-do-you-install-a-windows-executable-r-package

Comment: Maybe it would be on topic on superuser?

Comment: Do we want installation of scientific software packages to be within our scope?

Comment: I've added a [question](http://meta.scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/115/how-appropriate-are-software-package-specific-installation-questions/116#116) on meta, along with my opinion, and I'd be interested to hear your (and the rest of the community's) opinions.

Comment: Detailed instructions for installing packages can be found on the [Comprehensive R Archive Network (CRAN) web site](http://cran.r-project.org/) on [this page](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-admin.html#Installing-packages). So far as I can tell, there is no such thing as an "executable R package"; there are binary R packages. I'm going to close the question for the time being as off-topic without migrating it; migration or reopening is an option in the future.

Comment: Based on the [discussion on meta](http://meta.scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/115/how-appropriate-are-software-package-specific-installation-questions), I'm re-opening the question, and moving the answer in my comment to an actual answer, since the Windows installation process for R packages can be nontrivial.

Comment: Another stackoverflow answer: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4918553/1022

Answer (score 4):

Copied from a comment I made above during discussions about topicality:

Detailed instructions for installing packages can be found on the [Comprehensive R Archive Network (CRAN) web site](http://cran.r-project.org/) on [this page](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-admin.html#Installing-packages). So far as I can tell, there is no such thing as an "executable R package"; there are binary R packages.